# good practise to add method to class to check consistency?

Tags: python, unit-testing, class, testing, automated-tests

I am writing a package which has a lot of complicated indexing for a hierarchical clustering algorithm. I have written unit tests, and in these test I have created a method which checks that some values in the class are consistent with each other. This means I can test if a method breaks it. However, I was wondering if it is good/bad practice to have a method like this defined in the class itself as I haven't seen this before.

As requested here is a minimal example. In my application the variables are a matrix of index allocations for the nested clusters, and a list of counters for the nested cluster and an integer counter for the top layer cluster. Counter just means how many are filled, so when it gets to a level I run a method which removes the clusters which have been emptied.

```
    class ClassName(object):
        _variable_one = None
        _variable_two = None

        def __init__(self, var1, var2):
             # set variables
             self._variable_one = var1
             self._variable_two = var2

        def _checker(self):
             # check some relationship between _variable_one and _variable two
             # and assert it is still true, for example:
             assert self._variable_one == self._variable_two

        def do_stuff(self):
             # perform a method which changes _variable_one and _variable two
             # check your changes do not 'break' the model
             self._checker()
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: A basic example would help make this a clearer question.

Comment: would you ever need a different "checker" for the same "do_stuff", like dependent on the input variables?

Comment: No, I would only need one, which would work for every method in the class which changes cluster allocations. The checker will always perform the same checks.